# mark number by changing the number color if found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in making my code work I will start to explain:

1- the code will look to this sheet and take the loco number [sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IaQQ.png)

2- It will change the color if the number matches the one in the other sheet the color for that value will change to red [sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdQBx.png)

3-the code should do it by row so if the number exists in other rows it will not change their colors (only the row it self will change).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ContainWord1 As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim x As Integer

   Active.Sheet11
Active.Sheet14

finalrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To finalrow



ContainWord1 = Sheet15.Cells(x, 10).Value

  If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 8).Value = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 8).Font.Color = vbRed
   If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 10).Value = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 10).Font.Color = vbRed
    If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 12).Value = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 12).Font.Color = vbRed
     If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 14).Value = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 14).Font.Color = vbRed



  Next x


End Sub
```

When I use the code nothing happened

thank you :)

try one: I change the finalrow out of the loop and remove Characters

**the code after it works now:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ContainWord1 As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Range("H5:M100").Font.Color = vbBlack

finalrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To finalrow

ContainWord1 = Cells(x + 3, 25).Value

  If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 8).Value2 = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 8).Font.Color = vbRed
   If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 10).Value2 = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 10).Font.Color = vbRed
    If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 12).Value2 = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 12).Font.Color = vbRed
     If Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 14).Value2 = ContainWord1 Then Sheet11.Cells(x + 3, 14).Font.Color = vbRed



  Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: The first `Characters` you are changing is character 5, but the text only has 4 characters.  Something makes me think your use of specific characters is not what you intended and you wanted to change the font of the whole cell.  If so, get rid of `.Characters(....)` and see if that does what you want.

Comment: you can use this form:  `Cells(x, "J")`  ... makes it easier to keep track of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting finalrow, thus you do not enter in the loop `For x = 2 to finalrow`. Thus nothing happens. Put `finalrow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row` outside the loop, thus it enters it.

Comment: @YowE3K - :). Btw, what is `Active.Sheet11`?

Comment: thx vityata try one: I change the finalrow location (out of the loop) and remove Characters but it colors every thing. (you are right about the finalrow place)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead of the four `If ...` statements

makes it easier to add/change columns and change starting row

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Sheet11.Range("h3,j3,l3,n3").Offset(x)
    If cel.Value = ContainWord1 Then cel.Font.Color = vbRed
Next cel
```

Comment: THANK YOU jsotola , I fixed the code and it is working .. I  used your code as well and it worked also